# Is there anything like a link or shared mount point for FAT32 folders in Linux/Android?

Tags: mount, android, symbolic-link, fat32, folder-redirection

I often want the same files to be accessed by different apps on my Android phone, but the apps look in different folders.  Is there a way to make two different folder paths on a FAT SD card point to the same file?  For EXT, I think I could do this with a symbolic or hard link, but those don't exist for FAT.  Can FAT be extended to support them?  Can Android use an EXT-formatted SD card?  Can a folder be mounted on top of another folder?

If this does exist, does it have any negative side effects?

Comment: They're just going to move you to android dude, just ask again there

Comment: It's more a Linux question than an Android question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible to mount a folder in another folder if you have root.

open adb or terminal (adb is preferred) and type

`mount -o bind /origdir /newdir`

This should have the same affect as `ln` and will work on FAT32 filesystem

Comment: Works fine.  Shows up in apps as if `/sdcard/newdir` has the same files as `/sdcard/origdir`, which is useful for sharing files between apps that look only in specific hardcoded folders.  You should mention that you have to `mkdir newdir` first, though.

Comment: does this stay after reboot?   I saw a response on another SE site saying this is lost at reboot: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/is-possible-to-make-symbolic-links-in-the-android-filesystem-and-how

Answer (score 4):

Endolith answer is best for your situation, but Sathya is wrong, there is also solution, if you really need to fake link(hardlink), see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545536/faking-symbolic-links-on-a-fat32-formatted-storage
Though i hadnt tried it on android.

Answer (score -1):

> Can Android use an EXT-formatted SD card?

Android can mount ext2 but the volume manager won't handle ext2-formatted SD cards.  (If you have rooted your phone you may be able to fix this.)

> Can a folder be mounted on top of another folder?

Yes.

Comment: "Yes."  How would you do that on Android?  Would it have the effect I want?